# Regex for pattern matching in shell script and extract the match part

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Hope you are doing.

I need help in regex in the shell script.

the input is:

`PM_path='SubNetwork=IMS,SubNetwork=IMS,MeContext=R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS'`**PM_path='SubNetwork=IMS,SubNetwork=IMS,MeContext=R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS'

the output I want as:

**R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS** that is everything after the last equal sign.

Right now I have implemented it as below:

```
if [[ $PM_path =~ MeContext=([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) ]]; then  
      NODE_NAME=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
 echo "the value is matched";
```

So here I have put a check at MeContext and this is a part of PM_path.

I wanted to make it more generic like select everything which appears after the last equal sign.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wanted to make it more generic like select everything which appears after the last equal sign.

You may use:

```
[[ $PM_path =~ .*=([^/]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS
```

`.*` matches longest possible text from start then we match a `=`. Finally we match and capture remaining string of 1+ non-`/` characters in `([^/]+)` that we print using `echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Hope you are doing good. I have one more issue.
The exact PM_path is "PM_Path=**"SubNetwork=IMS,SubNetwork=IMS,MeContext=R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS/"**

so after ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} the output is as R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS/ i.e with extra slash. Ccould you please help me out to get rid of slash..

Comment: @Chanchalsingh: Please check my updated answer now

Answer (score 5):

You could use `grep` here, with GNU `grep` please try following. Simply using `grep`'s -o and -P option(to enable PCRE regex). Then in regex matching everything till last occurrence of `=` and using `\K` to discard matched part and `.*` followed by it will print the rest of the value from variable.

```
echo "$PM_path" | grep -oP '.*=\K.*'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply get the value using Bash string manipulation:

```sh
PM_path="${PM_path##*=}"
```

Here, `${PM_path##*=}` means that you want to remove as many chars as possible from the left (`##*`) till the last `=` char.

See the [*10.1. Manipulating Strings* reference](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

> `${string##substring}`
> Deletes longest match of `$substring` from front of `$string`.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/tkkeSt):

```sh
PM_path='SubNetwork=IMS,SubNetwork=IMS,MeContext=R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS'
PM_path="${PM_path##*=}"
echo "$PM_path"
# => R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS
```

*ANSWER TO YOUR COMMENT*:

You [mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445227/regex-for-pattern-matching-in-shell-script-and-extract-the-match-part/67452343#comment119255107_67448271) you have a trailing `/` char at the end of your string. You can still use the same technique, remove `/` from the result obtained with the preceding step:

```sh
PM_Path="SubNetwork=IMS,SubNetwork=IMS,MeContext=R9NEXRERNFVCSS01_PS/"
PM_Path="${PM_Path##*=}"
PM_Path="${PM_Path/\//}"
echo "$PM_Path"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/iqRRmE), `PM_Path="${PM_Path/\//}"` removes the first `/` in the string.